# Mangage Customer edit display blank in magento admin panel

Tags: magento

We have Added this code

`"ini_set('display_errors',1);"`

in index.php but there is no error.
 Please tell me another solution. Is any problem in Database or server issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable developer mode from index.php

And check what is error display.

Comment: I have add first time this 
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

After add this in index.php

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

but there is no error displaying

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logs if you get some clue there.

Also, have you used any extension which is overriding the Customer management in admin. If yes, you can try to disable it once to identify the issue.

I hope you have ensured that its happening with the edit page and not for a particular customer.

Comment: We have disable all extension & check but problem still there

this display in all customer & we have not use any customer module.

In our staging site it is work proper after live it work but before 2 days It automatically not working

Comment: My Code is correct this problem in database can you suggest how to fix this problem